# Django - How does a query query itself?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have two models

```
Product
  id:
  delivery_date: DateTimeField
  contract: FK

Contract
  id:
  safety_days: IntegerField
```

I need to get the products to deliver in the next X days. This X are defined in the contract as safety_days.

```
products = Product.objects.filter(
   Q(delivery_date__lte=(datetime.datetime.now() + timedelta(days=contract__safety_days)))
)
```

However,I am not able to do:

```
days = contract__safety_days
```

I do not know how I can reference the object itself inside the query to do this dynamically.

Best regards,
Ruben Barros

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) for this query.
Your query would look the following way:

```
products = Product.objects.filter(
    Q(delivery_date__lte=(datetime.datetime.now() + timedelta(days=F('contract__safety_days'))))
)
```

Comment: Yes! that was what i was looking for :D